# Trying to build ConnectionKit example (but failing)

Tags: cocoa, xcode, frameworks

I've got the latest(?) [ConnectionKit](http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/) library by doing:

```
svn co http://opensource.utr-software.com/source/connection/tags/1.2.3/
```

Then went into the dir (1.2.3), opened *Connection.xcodeproj* with Xcode, set Mac OS X 1.5 | Release | Framework to build the framework -> Build successful.

Then went into 1.2.3/Example, opened *ConnectionApp.xcodeproj* with Xcode, but whatever I do the build fails.

All I'm getting is: 'Connection/Connection.h: No such file or directory' on:

```
#import <Connection/Connection.h>
```

And I'm guessing that the rest of the 43 errors I'm getting are all coming from here.

I tried adding the framework but I'm still getting said error - although I'm not sure that I'm doing this right.

I tried the following:

> To use the new method, choose the desired Target (not File Group) and select “Existing Frameworks…” from the “Add” contextual menu. In 3.0 this will give you the same file dialog as before, but in 3.1 it will bring up the Target’s Get Info panel to the General tab. The bottom portion of this pane shows the Target’s Linked Libraries. Clicking the “+” button beneath the list will bring up a list of known frameworks for the active SDK.

Also tried dragging and dropping to no avail. Same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Attaching a screenshot:

[Screenshot http://rusiczki.net/littlesnapper/DropletController.h%20-%20ConnectionApp.png](http://rusiczki.net/littlesnapper/DropletController.h%20-%20ConnectionApp.png)

[View full size](http://rusiczki.net/littlesnapper/DropletController.h%20-%20ConnectionApp.png)

Comment: Same grave problems with ConnectionKit here, but with Xcode 5. The farthest I got was getting it inside my project and compile without hiccups. But unfortunately without a "Connection.framework" or "ConnectionKit.framework" appearing in my main project. While I'd call my self quite experienced, I'm about to give up with ConnectionKit. As bad as it might sound: Karelia software has a quite neat FTP client in the store. So I'm forced to the assumption that the grave problems with getting ConnectionKit to work properly are on purpose ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Connection.h has the role "public" in the Connection framework target. If you click on the target the right panel should show you the list of files in the target and each header will either have private, project or public as its role.

Also try changing the angle brackets to quotes in the import statement i.e.

```
#imort "Connection/Connection.h"
```

Comment: I checked the roles in the framework and I had them set correctly. Turns out I had to move the framework into the build directory of the example to get rid of the import error. See my response.

Answer (score 0):

I advanced with this problem. I figured out I have to copy the framework in the build directories (Debug or Release). This way the error about `import` disappeared but now I have other errors, starting with:

> Cannot find protocol declaration for
>   'AbstractConnectionProtocol'

Note: It's just my luck that for my first serious Cocoa project ever, the best framework that offers what I need (FTP transfers) is undocumented and a pain to build.